# How do I pass params to Rails controller's callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The callback is like below.

```
class User
  include UserSettable

  before_action :set_user

  def show
    [Something with @user]
  end
end

class Group
  include UserSettable

  before_action :set_user
  ...
end
```

And the `set_user` is like below. And this method is defined in the controller concern.

```
module UserSettable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I have three questions.

- How do I pass params to callback method?
- Can the instance variable defined in concern be used in controller?
- Does this implementation deviate from the usual usage of rails?

Comment: You might also want to add `:new` and `:index` to `except: [:create]` list

Comment: The first two (sub-)questions you asked, you could easily try them out on your system and let us know the results. Don't be afraid to give it a shot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I pass params to callback method?

`params` of request will automatically be available to action. You don't need to pass it explicitly. Your code snippet is perfect use case of how it should be used.

> Can the instance variable defined in concern be used in controller?

You mean controller's concern. I think the instance variable defined there should be available. Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

> Does this implementation deviate from the usual usage of rails?

No

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I updated the code snippet. In this case, can I use [at]user defined in concern within show method?

Comment: @ngk yes. You can simply do `Rails.logger.info(@user.inspect)` to check